# How to Get Updated Calender Events from Office 365 using Visual Studio Client Libraries

Tags: office365

I have Successfully integrated my application with Office 365 using Visual Studio Client Libraries by following this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-calendar-tasks-client-library .Now suppose if any calender event(date) is modified in Office 365,I want to get that updated calender event only.Is that Possible? Please suggest me.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The Office 365 REST APIs don't currently have synchronization or notification capabilities. The closest you could come is to filter on the DateTimeLastModified property so that your queries only return items modified after a certain time.